# MPMoviePlayerController with custom controls

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

I added some custom controls to a MPMoviePlayerController. Ths is explicitly written in the documentation that tis is possible:

> You can add subviews to the view in this property. You might do this in cases where you want to display custom playback controls or add other custom content that is relevant to your application.

But this works only as long as I don't enter to fullscreen mode. When entering fullscreen mode the controls disappear. I tried to move the custom control view to front when entering the fullscreen mode, but that didn't had any effect. Is this just not working or what do I have to do to get custom controls in the fullscreen mode?

P.S. I'm working with iOS 3.2 on the iPad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the video in the fullscreen is rendered on a different view then the non fullscreen one. So the only thing to get this (at least what I discovered) is to implement your own fullscreen mode.
I filed a bug at apple. So let's hope they going to fix this in the next release.

Comment: did you get any reply? (from apple)

Comment: is there any progress resolving this bug?

Comment: We used a Support Incident on this. Finally it turned out that it is a bug in iOS 3.2 and there is definitely no workaround. At least it's fixed in 4.2

Comment: Is it? How do you do it in 4.2+?

Comment: I'm trying this on iOS 6.1 and it doesn't seem to work. Adding a subview to the player view works in non-fulscreen mode. but once you go fullscreen, the subview disappears.

Comment: OK so this was three years ago, what about today?

Comment: You need to re/add your subviews whenever the player changes from embedded to fullscreen mode - that worked 4 years ago and it still works fine today.